# WooCommerce как изменить цену на странице checkout?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На скрине показываю, что нужно изменить. Там эта маска, на которую я указал стрелочку, даётся бесплатно в одном экземпляре. Мне нужно уменьшить эту сумму на 350, то-есть чтобы ток одна была бесплатна. Итоговую цену я изменил, но мне нужно там тоже поменять.

Прошу писать только людей, которые реально могут помочь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте фильтр `woocommerce_get_price`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price', 10, 2 );
public function my_woocommerce_get_price($price, $product) {
    if ( is_checkout() && 777 === $product->get_id() ) {
        $price = 0;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Когда вставляю это, сайт не открывается с ошибкой "На сайте возникла критическая ошибка.".

Comment: и что в ошибке написано то?

Comment: А не, всё работает, я не так сделал. Проблема в другом. Я сделал так $price -= 350; (стоимость одного товара этого). Но это действие же применяется ко всем, а мне нужно что-бы только к одному экземпляру. То-есть образно закупил я 5 масок, ток 1 должна быть бесплатной.

Comment: лучше сделайте цена за штуку * (кол-во - 1) тогда не важно, какая цена будет у товара)

Comment: Функция выполняется два раза, по этому не работает) $price = 350 * $count; (count я получил ранее, с ним всё норм). Из-за срабатывание два раза, она в итоге увеличивается.

Comment: А нет. Короче, смотрите. Сколько товаров ты взял, столько раз выполнится. То-есть если я например ставлю $price - 5 и возьму 5 товаров, то цена будет 25. Когда я делаю так как сказали вы, выполняется два раза и складывается.

Comment: А что если просто сделать скидку 350р и все? global $order; $order->discount_total(350);

Comment: Можете помочь, в какую функцию это нужно вставить?) Скидка же будет действовать только на этот товар?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107269/discussion-between-wp-punk-and-youmixx).